# Ubuntu 12.10 download

Tags: downloads

I want to download Ubuntu 12.10 rather than 12.04 for my desktop PC, but I cannot find any .ISO image of this version on the Ubuntu website. Is there anywhere I can get it?

Comment: 12.10 is near end-of-life (take a look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). I suggest you go for 12.04LTS or a newer version from the 13.xx tree.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download Here
.................................
http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/